# Getting default server Unknown after configuring DNS by nslookup

Tags: dns, windows-server-2012, nslookup

I am new to windows server. I just installed DNS on windows 2012 server. Here is how it appeared after installing

[image: DNS Srver]

Then i went to DNS manager. I created a new Forward Primary zone and reverse zone. Here is the screen shot

[image: Forward Reverse Zones]

Then i created the record (A, MX, CNAME). Here are the screen shots of each

SOA:

[image: SOA]

Name Server:

[image: Name Server]

A Record:

[image: A Record]

MX Record:

[image: MX Record]

CNAME:

[image: CNAME]

Reverse lookup Zone:

[image: Reverse Lookup Zone]

After all that when i do nslookup, then i get Default Server: Unknown. Why ? Why i am getting unknown server

[image: nslookup]

Why i am getting unknown ?

Thanks

Comment: Try `ipconfig /flushdns` or Restarting DNS Service, or [this post](http://www.randika.info/2013/01/how-to-fix-nslookup-default-server.html)

Answer (score 1):

You did all correct, but you dont mentioned are you restart DNS service after that? After restart its working fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

From the quick google research it seems to be a reverse PTR record issue. Try recreating the PTR record. [Here is a NSLookup Unknown troubleshooting](http://www.randika.info/2013/01/how-to-fix-nslookup-default-server.html) for a bit older version. This might work for Server 2012 as well.